# How to change url for custom module

Tags: magento2

I have a module with page url http://hostname/affiliate/account/promo/

I want to change it to http://hostname/referafriend

can anyone suggest me how to achieve it.

Comment: You have to change in your controller file.

Comment: check with your frontend Namespace_Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml file... with 'frontName'

Comment: you need to rewrite your url. please refer : https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-url-rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

- `affiliate` is your `frontName` defined in `routes.xml`
- `account` is the controller name (inside your module Controller directory you have a `Account' dir)
- `promo` is the controller action (you have a `Promo.php` file inside `Controller/Account` directory)

To change te url you shoud have from `/affiliate/account/promo/` to `/referafriend`:

- `referafriend` as your `frontName` in routes.xml
- `index` as yout controller name
- `index` as you action

So you should change from `YourModule/Controller/Account/Promo.php` to `YourModule/Controller/Index/Index.php` and change `affiliate` to `referafriend` in routes.xml

Answer (score 0):

Generate a constructor file

```
/**
* @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\UrlRewriteFactory
*/
protected $_urlRewriteFactory; /**
* @param Context $context
* @param \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory
*/
public function __construct( 
Context $context, 
\Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\ResourceModel\UrlRewriteFactory $urlRewriteFactory
) { 
$this->_eavAttributeFactory = $eavAttributeFactory; 
parent::__construct( $context );
}
```

Fill in custom URL rewrite in execute method

```
$urlRewriteModel = $this->_urlRewriteFactory->create()
/* set current store id */
$urlRewriteModel->setStoreId(1);
/* this url is not created by system so set as 0 */
$urlRewriteModel->setIsSystem(0);
/* unique identifier - set random unique value to id path */
$urlRewriteModel->setIdPath(rand(1, 100000));
/* set actual url path to target path field */
$urlRewriteModel->setTargetPath("www.example.com/customModule/customController/customAction");
/* set requested path which you want to create */
$urlRewriteModel->setRequestPath("www.example.com/xyz");
/* save URL rewrite rule */
$urlRewriteModel->save();
```